# Usage of en dash in a CV

Tags: word-choice, punctuation, dates, dashes

I write the date in my résumé in the following format:

```
7/2017–present
4/2015–6/2017
8/2010–3/2015
```

Is this the right way to do it? I am asking because I also saw the following notation:

```
7/2017 – present
4/2015–6/2017
8/2010–3/2015
```

This notation doesn't seem to be consistent. But since the "en dash" can be interpreted as "to" the last notations also seems legit.

Which version is correct? And if both are not, what would be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of style. More often than not, an en dash is used (without any spaces), but it depends on what style guide is followed.

From *The Chicago Manual of Style* (6.78):

> The principal use of the en dash is to connect numbers and, less
>   often, words. With continuing numbers—such as dates, times, and page
>   numbers—it signifies *up to and including* (or *through*). For the sake of
>   parallel construction, the word *to* or *through* (or *until*), never the
>   en dash, should be used if the word *from* precedes the first element in
>   such a pair; similarly, *and* should be used if *between* precedes the
>   first element.
>
> The years 1993–2000 were heady ones for the computer literate.
>   For source citations and indexing, see chapters 14–16.
>   In Genesis 6:13–21 we find God’s instructions to Noah.
>   Join us on Thursday, 11:30 a.m.–4:00 p.m., to celebrate the New Year.
>   I have blocked out December 2016–March 2017 to complete my manuscript.
>   Her articles appeared in *Postwar Journal* (3 November 1945–4 February 1946).
>
> *but*
>
> She was in college from 2012 to 2016 (*not* from 2012–16).
>   He usually naps between 11:30 a.m. and 1:30 p.m. (*not* between 11:30
>   a.m.–1:30 p.m.)

Whatever style is used, it should be used consistently within the same text.

Note: I think your question actually used a hyphen, not an en dash.

Hyphen: -, en dash: –, em dash: —.